# Advice on Shortening My p5.js Code (for loop?)

Tags: image, for-loop, p5.js

I'm making a program that will randomize and load 6 different images next to each other each time the mouss is clicked.

```javascript
function mousePressed() {
   randomNum1 = floor(random(0,6));
   randomNum2 = floor(random(0,6));
   randomNum3 = floor(random(0,6));
   randomNum4 = floor(random(0,6));
   randomNum5 = floor(random(0,6));
   randomNum6 = floor(random(0,6));

   image(dieImages[randomNum1],0,0);
   image(dieImages[randomNum2],100,0);
   image(dieImages[randomNum3],200,0);
   image(dieImages[randomNum4],300,0);
   image(dieImages[randomNum5],400,0);
   image(dieImages[randomNum6],500,0);
}
```

I'm pretty sure that I can use a for loop somewhere, but I'm not positive how. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're already using an array for your images. The `dieImages` array basically holds a bunch of image variables. Why not do the same thing for your random numbers?

The syntax might look like this:

```
 randomNum[0] = floor(random(0,6));
 randomNum[1] = floor(random(0,6));
 randomNum[2] = floor(random(0,6));
 randomNum[3] = floor(random(0,6));
 randomNum[4] = floor(random(0,6));
 randomNum[5] = floor(random(0,6));
```

Which you could shorten to use a `for` loop:

```
for(var i = 0; i < randomNum.length; i++){
  randomNum[i] = floor(random(0,6));
}
```

Then your `image()` calls use the `randomNum` variables as indexes. If the random numbers are in an array like we just saw, then the `image()` lines could be this:

```
image(dieImages[randomNum[0]],0,0);
image(dieImages[randomNum[1]],100,0);
image(dieImages[randomNum[2]],200,0);
image(dieImages[randomNum[3]],300,0);
image(dieImages[randomNum[4]],400,0);
image(dieImages[randomNum[5]],500,0);
```

Which you could shorten to just be this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < randomNum.length; i++){
  image(dieImages[randomNum[i]], i * 100, 0);
}
```

Side note: it might be easier if you refactor this code to use an object that holds an image and a position, instead of two [parallel arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_array) that hold related data in corresponding indexes.

Comment: Hi, can you tell me what 'randomNum.length' does here?

Comment: @KatK Your best friend is Google. Try searching something like "JavaScript array length" for a ton of results. Let me know if you have a more specific question after looking through those.